# Error while loading .tmux.conf

Tags: osx, tmux, macintosh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to bind some keys to some certain commands in my .tmux.conf. The commands are as follows

```
bind-key C-c send-keys -t right \
"import os;clear = lambda: os.system('clear');clear()\;" \; send-keys -t right C-m
```

I am getting the following error, when I run tmux.

```
.tmux.conf:75 Unknown Error \
```

I am currently running `oh-my-zsh` on mac-osx, in the background, and I am not sure why am I getting this error.

P.S. My [tmux configuration](https://pastebin.com/RnRzcipG)

Comment: Basically it is throwing an error after "import os;clear = lambda: os.system('clear');clear()\;" at \;

Comment: I have also tried adding C-m at the end like this   bind-key C-c send-keys -t  right "import os; clear = lambda: os.system('clear'); clear();'  C-m . It gives the error Unknown-Command C-m then also.

Comment: Could you give some context as to the problem you're trying to solve? Clear the screen?

That looks like python... how exactly is python invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but I just don't like it though

```
bind-key C-c run-shell "tmux send-keys -t right \"import os;clear=lambda: 
os.system('clear'); clear()\"; 
tmux send-keys -t right C-m;"
```

For some reason I don't know why is this not working

```
bind-key C-c send-keys -t right "import os;clear=lambda: 
os.system('clear'); clear();" C-M
```